# Change ajax form submit value and state onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have an ajax form which am using to process data without refreshing the page. Everything works, except the submit button isn't animated which is a problem if you are using ajax.

I have tried several suggestions from here methods to get it animated but no luck.

My script for the ajax is;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitform').ajaxForm({
            target: '#error',
            success: function() {
            $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

process.php looks like this;

```
<?php

if((strlen($_POST['fname']) < 1 )){

    if(strlen($_POST['amount']) < 1 ){
        $emailerror .= '<span>Kindly enter full name</span>';
    }

} else { ?>
<span>Thank You</span>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo $emailerror; ?>
```

And the form is a simple form;

```
<form id="submitform" action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" />
<select name="values"><option value="1">Value 1</option></select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

When I click on submit, the form is sent to process.php and after a successful validation, the form is processed and a thank you page is displayed else an error is displayed. What I want to do is, when the user clicks submit, the submit button value should change to 'processing...' and become disabled. If the validation returns an error, the submit button should return to normal state.

**Update:**
When I add a select input to the form, the script below stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is to modify the button itself, try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var btnSubmit = $('#submitform');
   btnSubmit.ajaxForm({
     target: '#error',
     success: function() {
       $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
       btnSubmit.text("Send form"); // put your normal text
       btnSubmit.removeAttr("disabled");
     },
     error: function() {
       // enable and put the normal text in case of error
       btnSubmit.text("Send form"); // put your normal text
       btnSubmit.removeAttr("disabled");
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
        btnSubmit.text("Proccesing...");
        btnSubmit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
     }
   });
});
```

EDITED

Sorry for wrong post, I didn't see your HTML tags, so having your HTML, please modify your markup a little bit, just add an ID to your submit button, like this

```
<form id="submitform" action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" />
<input id="submitterButton" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and then you can use in the JS part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var btnSubmit = $('#submitterButton');
   $('#submitform').ajaxForm({
     target: '#error',
     success: function() {
       $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
        btnSubmit.val("Proccesing...");
        btnSubmit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
     },
     complete: function(){
       btnSubmit.val("Send"); // put your normal text
       btnSubmit.removeAttr("disabled");
     }
   });
});
```

so beforeSend will execute before ajax execute.

Hope it can fix your problem.

Comment: hey Johuder, thanxxx for the effort mehn, but when I click on the submit button, the whole form disappears and only the "Send Form" is shown.

Comment: When you say modify the button itself, what do you mean? @Johuder

Comment: @JaySmoke sorry for answering late, I made a mistake when posting my example, I didn't look for the HTML tags that you gave us, it that case, please let me edit my post to give your a better answer, when I refer to modify the submit button itself I mean that you have to change the text and disabled state of the submit button.

Comment: Hi @Johuder I came across a bug, I am not sure what is causing it but when there's a select input field, the whole script doesn't work.

Comment: @JaySmoke hello , please can you post your current code to help you :)

Comment: I have updated my post above, the only difference now is the select input field which is causing the script to not work.

Answer (score 0):

the snippet below does the trick

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="submitform" action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Full Name" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('#submitform').submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('input[type="submit"]').val('Processing...');
   $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true); //assuming that you have a CSS to do that.

   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('submit').serialize(),
    url: $('submit').attr('action')
   }).done(function (result) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').val('Send');
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false); 
   }).fail(function (argument) {
    // handle faillure
   })

  });

 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Luiz, thanxxx for the effort, but when I click on submit, it changes to Processing... and that's it. The form isn't processed.

Comment: I dont know PHP, actually, so maybe there is an error on server side. Did you implemented the fail handler function? Did the dev tools shows something?

Comment: And am not really familiar with javascripting hehe, what do you put in the fail handler?

Comment: pretty much anything, usually an alert function is enough https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp